# Aspnetboilerplate how to handle inputs with multiple parameters in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate

I do not know if it's related to abp but I need an advice. Let's say I have "GetMyCustomEntityInput" and it has so many parameters. Since nswag/refresh.bat does not provide me that input class in service-proxies.ts file, should I implement my own GetMyCustomEntityInput in service-proxies.ts file and if so would it work like that and would it be a good approach? I wonder how the abp community handle this case so I wanted to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do things like `abp.services.project.customentity.get({param1: 23, orderby:"desc"})`

Comment: I think what you are asking, is if you should have to write your own DTO in Typescript. The answer is **yes**, it's a pain, but yes. I used a t4 template to create DTO classes in TS automatically.

Comment: You can run nswag to generate service-proxies.ts again if you changed something like AppService, API ... that affect your client app (angularjs)  ... Look at this tool https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this page for how to integrate the automated dynamic service webapi layer with angular services:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API#DocAngularSupport

Example:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app').controller('TaskListController', [
        '$scope', 'abp.services.tasksystem.task',
        function($scope, taskService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.tasks = [];
            taskService.getTasks({
                state: 0
            }).success(function(result) {
                vm.tasks = result.tasks;
            });
        }
    ]);
})();
```

The parameters for you Dto input are NOT automatically converted to typescript, you have to create a dynamic object for input, so make sure you get the property names correct or it won't work.
You could use Typelite/t4 templates to automatically create your Dto's.